# SSRS List Each Folder Then Each Report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to list each folder followed by each report from an instance of SSRS.

I know how to retrieve all items and filter to folders for the headers but able struggling to list each report under each folder in the view. Note `Model.Reports` is decalred in the view model as `CatalogItem[]`.

```
@foreach (var report in Model.Reports)
{
    if (report.Type == ItemTypeEnum.Folder)
    {
        <h2>@report.Name</h2>
        //List here each report in folder.
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how to iterate over each report in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [ReportService2010.ListChildren](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren(v=sql.120).aspx)